# powershellを使って文字列"(ダブルクォーテーション)を削除したいです。

Tags: powershell

タイトル通りですが、
powershellを使って文字列"(ダブルクォーテーション)を削除したいです。

現状

```
$s = $(get-count "c:¥work¥sample.txt")
$s
$s.trim(`"` )
```

なのですが、["]を認識させることが出来ません。

どなたかよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `get-count` は `Get-Content` のことですか？

Comment: すみません。間違っていたかも知れません。$s = $(get-Content "c:¥work¥sample.txt")←ここでテキストファイルを読み込んで、そのテキストファイルの中の["]を削除したいです。

Comment: ファイルの中身が複数行の場合読み込んだ結果は配列になりますので、その場合配列として例えば`foreach`を使うような必要があります。また、`trim`は文字列の両端について作用するので、そのような形式でない場合は`replace`を使用した方がいいかもしれません。

Answer (score 3):

PowerShellでダブルクォートを含む文字列を書きたい場合は、

- シングルクォートを使った文字列を使う：`'"'`
- バッククォートでエスケープする：`` "`"" ``

といった方法があります。バッククォートで囲む構文はありません。

で、例えば次のようになります。

```
PS C:\> $s = '"foobar"'

PS C:\> $s
"foobar"

PS C:\> $s.Trim('"')
foobar
```

参考 [文字列 - Windows PowerShell | ++C++; // 未確認飛行 C](http://ufcpp.net/study/powershell/string.html#string)

---

`Trim()` は文字列の両端で連続する文字を取り除くメソッドなので、文中の " を取り除きたい場合は `Replace()` や `-replace` 演算子（こちらは正規表現が使えます）を使います。

```
PS R:\> 'a"b"c"'.Replace('"', '')
abc

PS R:\> 'a"b"c"' -replace '"', ''
abc
```

また Get-Contents で複数行のテキストを読み込む場合は配列になるので `foreach` を使いますが、直接 `Replace()` メソッドや `-replace` 演算子を使っても同じ結果が得られます。

```
PS R:\> $s
"aa"
bb"cc

PS R:\> $s | foreach { $_.Replace('"', '') }
aa
bbcc

PS R:\> $s.Replace('"', '')
aa
bbcc
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。                          $s = $(get-count "c:¥work¥sample.txt")←ここでテキストファイルを読み込んでいるのですが、テキストファイルの中にある["]を削除する方法はありますでしょうか？